# Dont persist topic Kafka

Tags: java, apache-kafka, messaging

I have a use case for Kafka where I dont need the logs of some topics that are running on the server, some topics send a **lot** of messages while other not so much.

Currently the only "fix" I see was to set a pretty lax retention policy.

Thing is that I would like to keep the logs and persistent information for some other topics that are on the server, which are arguably more important to me.

What options do I have ?

Ideally I would like to discard logs and stored messages by topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set per-topic retention policies, yes.

Here’s an example using `kafka-topics`:

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper localhost:2181 \
                --alter \
                --topic MyTopic \
                --config retention.ms=1000
```

Comment: will this retention period affect only the persisted messages or will it cause messages in the memory to be discarded if the retention period is up? For some of the topics, I want messages to be available until the consumers read them even if it takes a longer time because of slow consumers, but meanwhile if the broker dies, I don't mind losing the messages that are not yet consumed.

Answer (score 1):

The retention settings can be set on a per-topic basis. You can do that either at creation time or alter the topic config once created. You can find the full list of topic configs on [Kafka's website](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#topicconfigs).

For topics you don't need to keep data, set retention limits that will delete data frequently.

On the other hand, for topics you need to keep the data, set retention limits that will keep the data for longer period of time.

For example, to set topic config when creating a topic (retention time=24hours):

```
kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper <ZK> --create --topic --partitions 1 --replication-factor 1 --config retention.ms=86400000
```

To update an existing topic:

```
kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper <ZK> --entity-type topics --entity-name <TOPIC> --alter --add-config retention.ms=86400000
```